# Video playback in Adaptive card of MS teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I get a message "Media playback is currently not supported in Adaptive Cards in Teams" on the adaptive card when rendered in the channel MS teams.

Although it seems its not officially supported ,i was wondering is there any workaround to play videos on adaptive card in MS Team Channel?
Any help would be  gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Playing video inside an Adaptive Card is not supported. You could try opening a [task module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) on click of a Adaptive card button and play a video inside TaskModule.Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules#example-1---youtube-video) to load a youtube video inside Taskmodule.